# Okhttp 2.7.5 -> 4.10.0

Tags: okhttp

I am trying to update the okhttp (Com.squareup.okhttp) 2.7.5 to okhttp3 (Com.squareup.okhttp3) 4.10.0

The implementation docs are not available online when searched for it.

Its EOL (end of life) for 2.7.5, while upgrading it iam facing lot of implementation errors w.r t the client generation and interceptors.

Can someone help with the implementation docs or links to solve my above problem?

Implementation for 4.10.0 is not available and the dependency from maven repo brings the kotlin files instead of JAVA classes

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the okhttp 3 upgrade docs, which walk through API changes from 2.x through the current release.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelogs/changelog_3x/#version-300-rc1

Comment: Javadocs are present online till 3.14.9, I want for >4.9.x